# Change from days to seconds on jquery.cookie.js plugin

Tags: jquery, cookies, plugins, format

Any idea how I would get this (working) bit of js to be formatted in seconds for the expiration parameter set by the plugin by https://github.com/carhartl/?

Here is what I have, working well (using in conjunction with ominflowWindow, also):

```
function OverlayClose() {
        jQuery(".ow-overlay, .modal").hide("slow");
    }
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery.cookie('product_2min_modal') == null) {
        jQuery.cookie('product_2min_modal', 'yes', {
            expires: 1,
            path: '/'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery('div.modal').omniWindow() // create modal
            .trigger('show');
        }, 5000 // and show it
        );
    }
});
```

Could I code straight into the function, something like this?

```
function OverlayClose() {
            jQuery(".ow-overlay, .modal").hide("slow");
        }
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (jQuery.cookie('product_2min_modal') == null) {
            jQuery.cookie('product_2min_modal', 'yes', {
                expires:  
var date = new Date();
 var minutes = 2;
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
 $.cookie("product_2min_modal", { expires: date });
,
                path: '/'
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                jQuery('div.modal').omniWindow() // create modal
                .trigger('show');
            }, 5000 // and show it
            );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax errors

```
function OverlayClose() {
    jQuery(".ow-overlay, .modal").hide("slow");
}
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if (jQuery.cookie('product_2min_modal') == null) {
        var date = new Date();
        var minutes = 2;
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        jQuery.cookie('product_2min_modal', 'yes', {
            expires: date,
            path: '/'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! That's gone and done it! Thanks for setting it straight Arun. Brilliant.